# Activity is recreated after resuming app from task manager list

Tags: java, android

I have an activity where we click image using,

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "NewPicture");
imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
```

and have activity for result as,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
    }
}
```

after clicking and saving photo `onDestroy()` is called so, I have used `onSaveInstanceState(), onRestoreInstanceState()` to resume same activity without recreating it when resumed from background(kept in background for 1 min or 10 secs) still the activity is not restored.

Issue occurs in low memory device currently using **Samsung J1 with Version: 4.4.4, RAM:512 MB**

How to solve this? Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: does this issue only occurs in low memory device ? As you stated above.

Comment: Yes, Samsung J1 RAM:512 MB.

Comment: It shouldn't happen. Did you debug you program ? Can you add more piece of code that saving photo function

Comment: Yes I did debugging wherein, after resuming from background activity's **onCreate()** is called. Due to which captured image before entering background is not restored.

Comment: I set mImageBitmap by decoding uri received from `data.getString(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)` and then set the imageview @Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this once,
The problem with your device option 
1.got to settings
2.find the developer options
3.In Apps section check the Don't keep activities is false..

what it means image picker is detached form activity as new activity.
once user leaves the old activity it will kill by option on settings.

Check you may found..

Comment: I have the **Don't keep activities** option as unticked i.e false but still facing the mentioned issue @Ashokkumar Adichill

Comment: @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
    }  use this